# Why isn't the group by clause of this code being applied?

Tags: sql, oracle, select, group-by

I've grouped by the statements that I have selected, yet it's almost as if the database isn't even seeing the group by clause as it's throwing up an error and saying that emp_firstname isn't a single-group group function.

```
select emp_firstname, emp_surname, sum(timesheet_hours), sum(payroll_standard*grade_rate), sum((payroll_overtime*grade_rate)*1.5), sum(sum(payroll_standard*grade_rate) + sum((payroll_overtime*grade_rate)*1.5)), sum(payroll_pension)
from funtom_employee
join funtom_payroll on emp_id = payroll_emp
join funtom_timesheet on timesheet_id = payroll_timesheet
join funtom_grade on emp_grade = grade_id
where payroll_date between '1-Apr-2014' and '31-Mar-2015'
group by emp_firstname, emp_surname
```

Comment: There are nested SUMs, what are you trying to achieve?

Comment: When I tried a SUM(SUM()), I got "nested group function without GROUP BY"

Comment: I'm trying to pull back the data in the select statement and applying SUM to get total values for those pieces of data. 

I just need to know why I keep getting a single-group group function error even though I've grouped by what I've seleced?

Comment: You don't need a sum there. sum(payroll_standard*grade_rate) + sum((payroll_overtime*grade_rate)*1.5) would suffice.

Answer (score 1):

The confusion in the error message arises because Oracle supports nested aggregation function.  In other words, this (nonstandard) syntax is allowed:

```
SELECT AVG(MAX(salary))
FROM employees
GROUP BY department_id;
```

Such a nested function is equivalent to:

```
SELECT AVG(maxsalary)
FROM (SELECT MAX(salary) as maxsalary
      FROM employees
      GROUP BY department_id
     ) e
```

Hence, the nesting of the `sum()`s is not an error by itself -- although it would be in other databases.  The problem is that your query mixes levels of aggregation.  Hence, the weird error message referring to the keys, rather than the columns being aggregated.

As mentioned in a comment, you don't need nested aggregations:

```
select emp_firstname, emp_surname, sum(timesheet_hours),
       sum(payroll_standard*grade_rate),
       sum((payroll_overtime*grade_rate)*1.5),
       (sum(payroll_standard*grade_rate) +   
        sum((payroll_overtime*grade_rate)*1.5)
       ),
       sum(payroll_pension)
from funtom_employee join
     funtom_payroll
     on emp_id = payroll_emp join
     funtom_timesheet
     on timesheet_id = payroll_timesheet join
     funtom_grade
     on emp_grade = grade_id
where payroll_date between '1-Apr-2014' and '31-Mar-2015'
group by emp_firstname, emp_surname;
```

That said, your version of the query is probably incorrect anyway.  If a single employee has multiple or missing rows in any of the tables, the `sum()`s are likely to be off.  I would guess, for instance, that you'll get a Cartesian product for timesheets and payrolls.

If this is a problem and you want help here, then ask *another* question and include sample data and desired results.

In addition, learn to use table aliases and qualify your column names.  It helps clarify where columns are coming from.